# Showing ( 'Figure id ='1001'...) as Output On Plotting Graph using Bokeh on HTML page with CSV and DateTime

Tags: python, django, bokeh

I want to Plot Graph Containing Multiple Companies( Mult-line Graph ), But Getting output as Figure(id='1001', ...)

```
gref = ref.head()
p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime')
gref['Date'] = pandas.to_datetime(ref['Date']) 
group = gref.groupby(pandas.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D'))['Open', 'Close', 'High'].sum()
group = group / 1000
source = ColumnDataSource(group)
p.line(x='Date', y='Open', line_width=2, source=source, legend='High')
p.line(x='Date', y='Close', line_width=2, source=source, color=Spectral3[1], legend='Close')
p.line(x='Date', y='High', line_width=2, source=source, color=Spectral3[2], legend='Open')
p.title.text = 'Stock Analysis'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Values'

return render(request,'result.html',{'graph':p})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually use one of the functions for embedding Bokeh content, such as `json_items` or `components`. There is extensive documentation on all the embedding options:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html